# How can I print specific length of output? Like %d to be always 50 spaces out of the line?

Tags: c

So If I have an output like

```
Hello How are you         500
Halllo                    500
```

And that "500" is always supposed to be there at that specific position no matter what came infront of it what would needed to be put?

I've tried adding things like

```
printf ("10%d", w.e);
printf ("\t\t%d", w.e);
```

but the words like "hello how are you" and "hallo" always influence it and move it further along the same line. How can I position the 500 output to always be in one place?

Answer (score 6):

You need to right pad the preceding word i.e. `Hello How are you` and `Halllo`. Once its padded then `500` will always start with same position.

You can right pad the string as:

```
      printf("%-30s", "Hello How are you");
      printf("%-30s", "Halllo");
```

This will assign 30 char length to the string. Your number will follow the next.

Answer (score 1):

You can use printf to specify the minimum number of characters that the leading string should occupy, just as you would when formatting a numeric value.

In fact, you can print both in one call to printf (pseudocode):

```
format_string = "%-30s%5.0d";
leading_text = "hello";
number = 500;
printf(format_string, leading_text, number);
```

Answer (score 1):

something like this?

```
printf("%-50s%d\n", "Hello How are you", 500);
printf("%-50s%d\n", "Halllo", 500);
```

prints out:

```
Hello How are you                                 500
Halllo                                            500
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternate way to do it that might be more flexible:

```
printf("%*d\n", 50-printf("Halllo"), 500);
```